# VBA - Check if a cell's content is bold

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, cell

I'm currently trying to create a calendar in Excel using VBA.
Now I need to check if a cell in column B is formatted bold. Due the fact that the line which is formatted bold can change its position, I need to check every single cell in column B, if its content is bold.

My current code:

```
Sub ScanBlock1()

Dim Zelle As Integer
Dim Cell As String
Dim found As Integer

Zelle = 7
Zell = "B" & Zelle
found = 0

'CopyCat.OpenCopyCat
Windows("Preset.xlsm").Activate

Do While found = 0
    Windows("Preset.xlsm").Activate
    Range(Zell).Select
    If Range(Zell).Font.Bold Then
        'Save start and end for copycat
        found = 1
    Else
        Zelle = Zelle + 2
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

While trying this, I ran in to multiple problems.

First problem I have is, Excel just won't automatically activate the requested window. I don't know why. It worked all the time in other projects.

Second problem: I always get an overflow error in my `IF` Statement.
I think that it's caused by Excel not activating my requested window.
EDIT: Because many people already wrote that it is an overflow error because NO BOLD CELL IS FOUND, the window I'd like to open/select is "full" of bold cells.

Comment: Because your loop is infinite when no bold cell is found

Comment: @JohnyL I know. But why won't excel select the wanted window? in that file there are multiple bold cells...

Comment: in other words, found never becomes 0, thus the loop reaches last row + 1 - overflow.

Comment: And there's no need to activate workbook in a loop because you already activated it before loop!

Comment: @JohnyL that was to try to get it to work. But it didn't activate as expected.

Comment: Does it give error when `Windows("Preset.xlsm").Activate` is being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Preset.xlsm must be open if you want to Activate it.
2. Capture the error within your app.
3. The second Activation (within the loop) in not necessary
4. You increase the value of zell**E** (endlessly) but you do not update **Zell**

Try this:

```
Zelle = 7
zMAX=1000

found = 0
Windows("Preset.xlsm").Activate
if Err.Number <> 0 then goto errorlabel   ' process error

Do While found = 0 or Zelle < zMAX
    Zell = "B" & Zelle
    If Range(Zell).Font.Bold Then
        'Save start and end for copycat
        found = 1
    Else
        Zelle = Zelle + 2
    End If
Loop

If Zelle >= zMAX then
   Msgbox "Problem!"
Endif
```

I personnaly prefer direct cell references instead of bothering with strings, so here you are an alternativ solution:

```
zMAX=1000
Windows("Preset.xlsm").Activate
if Err.Number <> 0 then goto errorlabel   ' process error

for Zelle = 7 to zMAX Step 2
    If Cells(Zelle, 2).Font.Bold Then Exit For ' "2" for column "B"
Next
If Zelle >= zMAX then
   Msgbox "Problem!"
Else
   ' Bold found, Save start and end for copycat
Endif
```

Comment: Hi! The worksheet is being opened by "copycat". The second activation was just to try to get the activation to work. Just realised that you're right about the updating thing... Lemme try something

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't even had to use your code, just had to update "zell". Now it works perfectly fine. I just forgot that VBA isn't java... xD

Answer (score 0):

You have defined Zelle as integer, it may be maximally 32767 while Excel has about one million rows. The quick solution would be changing declaration:

```
Dim Zelle As Integer
```

But it may take a long time to run this macro. You should rather restrict this to UsedRange and use object loop. Like:

```
Dim cl as Range

For each cl in Workbooks("Preset.xlsm").Worksheets(1).UsedRange
  If Range(Zell).Font.Bold Then
     'Do something
  End If
Next cl
```

This will work for the first sheet of Preset.xlsm but you can indicate other sheet of course.

@comment below: Why iterating over all cells in UsedRange? OP needs only column B.

well, it would be faster this way:

```
For each cl in Workbooks("Preset.xlsm").Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(2)
```

Comment: Why iterating over all cells in UsedRange? OP needs only column B.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look in to it. Not sure yet, if this fixes my problem, but I'll try.